# Can Appium be used to tap on coordinates on an Unity or Cocos2d game, running over iOS or Android?

Tags: android, ios, appium

I would like to know if Appium can be used just to do clicks on the screen coordinates of a game made in Unity or Cocos2d, even without any web response from the device after the click. The idea is to do clicks on the device, and check the results visually. We don't want to edit the code or the game in any way, just with the IPA or apk as it is. Thanks

Comment: Appium provides Screen Coordinates base touch by using TouchAction. Could your try it out.   TouchAction action1 = new TouchAction(driver).press(x,y);  action1.perform().    Give your coordinates in x,y in press().

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, I think I'm going to do a test.

Comment: https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/TouchAction.html